# FlexboxLayoutManager item flickering on scrolling of another Recycler View

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I have `2 recyclerView`, RecyclerView 1, having layoutManager with `app:layoutManager="com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager"` & another RecyclerView 2, having `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`.

The first `recyclerview` item is flickering when scrolling on another recyclerView. It's working fine when item count of RecyclerView 1 is less than 6 or 7.

Please check the video link for the issue reference(0:18s - 0:46s): https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_wa3vd5H7QKh0fgj6Sh310ZNlt2TeG1/view?usp=sharing

Please find the code-snippet below:

activity_personal_activities.xml

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSave"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeaderTitle">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvConditionsSelected"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_0"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_20"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_24"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_0"
                    app:layoutManager="com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/dp_100"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:spanCount="2"
                    tools:itemCount="4"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/inflate_conditions_selected" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvConditions"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_7"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvConditionsSelected"
                    tools:itemCount="5"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/inflate_conditions" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Setting up adapter:

```
(bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.itemAnimator as? DefaultItemAnimator)?.supportsChangeAnimations = false
bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.adapter = adapter
```

ScrollToPosition of RecyclerView 1, On Adding new Item

```
bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.scrollToPosition(adapterList.size - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the flicker issue & the Problem was with the first recyclerView height. So I fixed this issue by adding a fixed height initially. If you see in my query, recyclerView height is `android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_0"` & `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/dp_100"` that is causing the flicker on the FlaxBoxLayoutManager recyclerView.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvConditionsSelected"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_36"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_12"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_24"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cvSearch"
    tools:itemCount="4"
    tools:listitem="@layout/inflate_conditions_selected" />
```

So, I'm changing the height of recyclerView programmatically

```
override fun updateRecyclerViewHeight() {
    val flexSize = (bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.layoutManager as? FlexboxLayoutManager)?.flexLinesInternal?.size
            ?: return
    when (flexSize) {
        3 -> changeRecyclerViewHeight(SizeUtils.dp2px(this,100F))
        2 -> changeRecyclerViewHeight(SizeUtils.dp2px(this,72F))
        1 -> changeRecyclerViewHeight(SizeUtils.dp2px(this,36F))
    }
}

override fun changeRecyclerViewHeight(height: Int) {
    val params = bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.layoutParams
    params?.height = height
    bViewDataBinding?.rvConditionsSelected?.layoutParams = params
}
```